# Data Scraping with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am very new at using R and I am trying to scrape a table off a webpage. I think I am having trouble identifying the CSS selector and that's why I am getting an error message but I'm not sure. Can anyone take a look at this and help me out?  If it's easier - I really only need the maintenance information - not the whole table, but I couldn't figure out how to obtain that either.

The code I am using:

```
library('rvest')
library('xml2')
url<- 'https://www.kbb.com/toyota/rav4-hybrid/2019/le/?vehicleid=441180&intent=buy-new'
temp <- url %>% read_html %>% html_nodes('.col-base-6') %>% html_table()
temp[[1]]
```

> ```
> Error in temp[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
> ```

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me out with this!

Thanks,
Lisa

Comment: `url %>% read_html %>% html_nodes('.col-base-6')` appears to give an empty nodeset, so yes, the selection is not working.

Comment: Right - so how do I figure out what the correct selector is? I have tried with the chrome selector gadget and using inspect but just can't seem to figure it out

Comment: I'm not sure what the maintenance information you're looking for is? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I just need maintenance price